# How do I implement async generators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I have subscribed to a MQ queue. Every time I get a message, I pass it a function that then performs a number of time-consuming I/O actions on it.
The issue is that everything happens serially.

A request comes in, it picks up the request, performs the action by calling the function, and then picks up the next request.

I want to do this asynchronously so that multiple requests can be dealt with in an async manner.

```
results = []
queue = queue.subscribe(name)
async for message in queue:
    yield my_funcion(message)
```

The biggest issue is that my_function is slow because it calls external web services and I want my code to process other messages in the meantime.
I tried to implement it above but it doesn't work! I am not sure how to implement async here.

I can't create a task because I don't know how many requests will be received.  It's a MQ which I have subscribed to.  I loop over each message and perform an action.  I don't want for the function to complete before I perform the action on the next message. I want it to happen asynchronously.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question? The title and body seem unrelated – there are no attempts to write async generators, or any async code for that matter, in the question. Writing ``async`` generators works the same as regular generators – what specific problem do you have doing that? Your code as shown is not ``async``, how does it relate to async generators? Do you actually need ``async``, or just any kind of concurrency such as threads?

Comment: I want to use async so that I can run the my_function asynchronously without waiting for the result for each message before taking the next message

Comment: And your question is what, then? How to call the function asynchronously? How to rewrite it async? How to finish the generator?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, what you need is a queue that your request handlers fill, and that you read from from the code that needs to do something with the results.

If you insist on an async iterator, it is straightforward to use a generator to expose the contents of a queue. For example:

```
def make_asyncgen():
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    async def feed(item):
        await queue.put(item)
    async def exhaust():
        while True:
            item = await queue.get()
            yield item
    return feed, exhaust()
```

`make_asyncgen` returns two objects: an async function and an async generator. The two are connected in such a way that, when you call the function with an item, the item gets emitted by the generator. For example:

```
import random, asyncio

# Emulate a server that takes some time to process each message,
# and then provides a result. Here it takes an async function
# that it will call with the result.
async def serve(server_ident, on_message):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))
        await on_message('%s %s' % (server_ident, random.random()))

async def main():
    # create the feed function, and the generator
    feed, get = make_asyncgen()

    # subscribe to serve several requests in parallel
    asyncio.create_task(serve('foo', feed))
    asyncio.create_task(serve('bar', feed))
    asyncio.create_task(serve('baz', feed))

    # process results from all three servers as they arrive
    async for msg in get:
        print('received', msg)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: but I can't create a task because I don't know how many requests will be received.  It's a MQ which I have subscribed to.  I loop over each message and perform an action.  I don't want for the function to complete before I perform the action on the next message. I want it to happen asynchronously.

Comment: @InfoLearner In this example I don't create one task for each message, but one task for each subscription. Either way, it's just guesswork because no one understands what you actually need from your description. Please edit the question to include more of your code, otherwise it will remain unanswerable.